# ReactNative with Redux - FlatList scrollToEnd

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I need to scroll FlatList component to end after it receive new data (in my case new messages). I tried to use `setTimeout` etc. and FlatList never scrolled. I use redux architecture and I don't have accesss to `setState` method a I never call 
it manualy.

I use `connect` method:

```
export default connect(
    (state: IAppState) => mapPropsToState(state.chat),
    mapPropsToDispatch
)(Chat)
```

State:

```
export interface IChatState {
    messages: Message[]
}
```

Where and when should I call `scrollToEnd` method.

Comment: add a code of your FlatList and attempting make a scroll pls

Answer (score 0):

Theres a property called onEndReached of flat lists as following:

```
 <FlatList
  onEndReached={this.handleEnd}
  onEndReachedThreshold={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 0.5} />
 </Flatlist>
```

Then create a method to handle end, I use a method that will add +1 to my current page and then fetch the data in another method which will populate list:

```
 handleEnd = () => {
    this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1,
    }, () => this.fetchData());
}
```

If you want your list to add more information then just concatenate the list, heres my fetch method (I'm using state but in redux works the same)

```
 this.setState({
                data:[...this.state.data, ...res.results],
                error:res.error || null,
                loading:false,
                refreshing: false,
               });
```

And in this way you add more information to the list, I hope this helps you!